# Why do layers disappear in ArcScene when I try to drape them to the TIN?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, 3d-analyst, arcscene, tin

I'm new. I did see this was asked a couple years ago, but I didn't understand the answer. It said *It's the projection. You're in ArcScene so be sure all of your layers are in Conic!* I have no idea what conic means in terms or ArcGIS or ArcScene. I looked it up and found nothing.

Why do layers disappear in ArcScene when I try to drape them to the TIN?

I could set the elevation offset at 0 or 10 or 20 and it happens every time to the trees, construction and contours layers. 2 other layers remain, but they look messed up.
I saw a possible reason was the graphics card. I have an Intel UHD graphics card on this ASUS laptop.

Other specs:
Windows 10
RAM: 8 GB
Processor: Intel Core i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60 GHZ - 1.80 GHZ
64 bit OS, x64-based processor
ArcGIS 10.7

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to reference the question with the answer you didn't understand, and include details on the operating system, RAM, graphics card, and exact release of ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Such error often occurs if input layers are not projected to common projected coordinate system. You may check whether your layers are projected or not by seeing layer properties.

Comment: Trees, construction, contour and tin all have this:  
Projected Coordinate System: NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_17N  
Projection: Transverse_Mercator  
Hillshade and pan2006 have this:  
XY Coordinate System: North_American_1983_UTM_Zone_17N

Comment: I re-did it with NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_17N Transverse Mercator as the coordinate system for everything and it still does the same thing.